# Customize Top Panel / Global Menu / Super-Wingpanel in Elementary OS Luna

Tags: osx, theme, elementary-os, menu, osx-finder

How on ElementaryOS change Wingpanel on **Top Panel** / **Global Menu** / **Super-Wingpanel** like OS X ?

[image]

Comment: How have you changed the wingpanel and added the global menu ?

Comment: @Chlebta Try install [Meta Panel](http://goo.gl/En9Lef).

Answer (score 3):

You have to open new administrator window, to do this type:  `gksu pantheon-files` in terminal enter your password, then navigate to `usr/share/themes/elementary(or other theme)/gtk-3.0` , open `apps.css` (with scratch) and you have to find :

```
 /*********
 * Panel *
 ********/

 .panel {
    background-color: alpha (#000, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

for example if you want to make the panel gray you have to change the zeros  in to d8d8d8 and the other numbers are for transparency (i think form 0.1 to 0.9)

```
.panel {

    background-color: alpha (#d8d8d8, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
```

For the fonts you have to find in this :

```
.composited-indicator {

    background-color: @transparent;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 2px;
```

and to change the 3 f to zeroes  :

```
.composited-indicator {

    background-color: @transparent;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 2px;
```

then close scratch and type in terminal `killall wingpanel` and you are ready.